# How to make Chrome exit process when all tabs are closed?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I'm on MacOS 12.4 and starting Chrome with `--user-data-dir=` arg. It opens and runs fine, however when I close every tab, it just hides, but keeps running. Is there a way to set it up so that it closes completely when all the tabs are closed?

Comment: You'd need a 3rd party app. The behaviour you describe is Mac-standard for any multi-document app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way most apps behave on MacOS X:

- The red X button in the corner of the screen closes the window
- Choosing `Quit` from the menu or clicking
  <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
  will close the app.

To totally close Chrome you should use the second close method for
the last tab.